# A reducer is removing state of another reducer from the store

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular2-observables

I am using NGRX and entity adapter. I have a component called `TransactionsComponent`. When this component is called the first time it loads a list of transactions as expected.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.dispatch( new actions.Query());
  }
```

I also have a `userReducer` that creates the `user ID` when the user is authenticated. When I first load the `TransactionsComponent` the transactions load as expected. When I navigate away from this page the `user` state is removed from the store and I am unsure why.

I've narrowed it down to this line of code causing the issue. 
`this.store.dispatch( new actions.Query());`
If I remove this line of code the `user` remains in the store when navigating between components.

Here is my reducer code for reference

```
export const transactionAdapter = createEntityAdapter<Transaction>();

export interface State extends EntityState<Transaction> {}

export const initialState: State = transactionAdapter.getInitialState();

// Reducer
export function TransactionReducer(
    state: State = initialState,
    action: actions.TransactionActions
) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case actions.ADDED:
          console.log('added ran');
          return transactionAdapter.addOne(action.payload, state);
      case actions.MODIFIED:
          return transactionAdapter.updateOne({
              id: action.payload.id,
              changes: action.payload
          }, state);
      case actions.REMOVED:
          console.log(action.payload);
          return transactionAdapter.removeOne(action.payload.id, state);
      default:
          console.log('default ran');
          return state;
    }
}

// Create the default selectors
export const getTransactionState = createFeatureSelector<State>('transaction');
```

My question is, why would this query be removing the user from the store?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not this reducer?
But perhaps you have another reducer that listens to the same action type.

Comment: I have an effect that listens to the action type however if I comment out the effect I still receive the same error.

I am receiving this error in the console - could this possible be related?

ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value for 'hidden': 'null'. Current value: 'false'.